# Cranks shift from side-to-side in new (second hand) bike

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, bearings

Just bought a new bike (second hand) and I've noticed that the cranks or perhaps the bottom bracket slides from side-to-side, almost as if the bottom bracket isn't long enough for the bottom bracket shell it sits in. Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: It might make it easier to provide an answer if you can capture this in a video. To keep things clear, perhaps you could put the bike upside down, then prop the phone/camera on something stable (chair, table etc), then share a link (youtube, google photos or similar).

Comment: Is it possible one of the cups of your bottom bracket is not fully tightened? That would allow lateral movement. We might not even need a video to verify this, a good photo would probably show that sufficiently.

Comment: Yeah, a photo would help. Or knowing the model of crank/frame/BB. Some spindles are a few mm too long intentionally, and come with a ring that clamps against the spindle to fix its position relative to the BB.

Comment: What kind of BB is that?

Comment: Can't help but think just drop in to the LBS. In all likelihood they can take a 30sec look and tell you what the problem is and what is needed to fix it

Comment: I’ll add a video shortly once I can get to my bike, but it as pressfit BB92, came with the AL ethirteen LG1 cranks on it

Answer (score 1):

Depends what kind of bottom bracket / crank you have..

If you have external bottom bracket like a Hollowtech, it can be a missing spacer ring, %99.

For older type bottom brackets, only thing that can cause such issue is busted bearings. But if they are not in really horrific situation, the play is almost impossible to feel or see.

Can you post a picture, at least?

Comment: I’ll add a photo as soon as I can get to my bike, but it’s a pressfit BB92 made by Ethirteen, with LG1 AL cranks

Comment: How much play do you have? As far as I know the spacers are 2.5mm - if you miss one spacer, you should have that much play, not less. If there is less play, maybe the crank is not tight enough, maybe its installed with debris on channels so it cannot be tightened enough